# Program that returns the sum of squares of only the positive numbers in a list

Tags: haskell

I tried to make a program in Haskell that returns the sum of squares of only the positive numbers in a list by using the filter function.

this is my first attempt:

```
sumsq :: [Int] -> Int
sumsq xs = foldr (+) 0 filter isPositive xs

isPositive :: Int -> Bool
isPositive x | x > 0     = True
             | otherwise = False
```

but it's not working and this is the error message I am getting :

```
Couldn't match expected type `[(Int -> Bool) -> [Int] -> Int]'
            with actual type `(a0 -> Bool) -> [a0] -> [a0]'
In the third argument of `foldr', namely `filter'
In the expression: foldr (+) 0 filter isPositive xs
In an equation for ` sumsq':
     sumsq xs = foldr (+) 0 filter isPositive xs
```

solution: 
after adding parentheses it's working correctly.

```
    sumsq :: [Int] -> Int
    sumsq xs = foldr (+) 0 (filter isPositive xs)

    isPositive :: Int -> Bool
    isPositive x | x > 0 = True
```

my new question is: why is it working with the parentheses and not without the parentheses ?

Comment: Hints: What should the third argument of `foldr` be? What is your current third argument? Can you fix this with parentheses?

Comment: it should be a list..

Comment: If you answer the other two questions in my comment, you're almost done. Try to wrap your head around it. Last hint: the current third argument is also contained in your error message. Is your current third argument a list?

Comment: it should be (filter isPositive  xs) .  but why is it working now and not before ?

Comment: Now, that's actually the interesting question, isn't it? ;). Add this information to your question, and add the actual question "Why is it working with parentheses, but not without", that should give you some nice answers.

Comment: You maybe want this: `foldr (+) 0 $ filter isPositive xs`

Comment: Other tip: `isPositive x = x > 0`, or just filter with `(> 0)`. `sum` is also a function.

Comment: `foldr (+) 0 filter isPositive xs` means `foldr((+), 0, filter, isPositive, xs)` - that is, call `foldr` with the arguements `(+), 0, filter, isPositive, xs`. This obviously makes no sense. While `foldr (+) 0 $ filter isPositive xs` means `foldr ((+), 0, filter (isPositive, xs))` - call `filter` with `isPositive, xs`, then call `foldr` with `(+), 0` and the result of the previous computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the parentheses, you're saying that `filter`, `isPositive`, and `xs` are all arguments to the fold.  That doesn't work because `foldr` expects a list as its third argument, not two functions followed by a list.  What you want is to pass the *result* of calling `filter isPositive xs` as the third argument to `foldr`, and that's what the parentheses specify.

You can get the same effect by writing `foldr (+) 0 $ filter isPositive xs`, since the `$` operator basically means to wrap a set of parentheses around everything that follows it.

Note that you can also write this function more concisely in point-free form (no need to mention `xs`) and without an explicit fold, using function composition:

```
sumsq = sum . map (^2) . filter (>0)
```